# Multiple photo upload using struts1

Tags: struts

We happened to get requirement to upload the multiple files ( like the gmail attachments ) using struts 1.3.5 and Ajax.

I happened to go thorough lot of resources but no luck.
Can someone shed light on this possibly by suggesting or pointing to some useful resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for a multiple file upload solution for my struts2 application. Since ajax form submit do not support image submission the only option to use was a hidden iframe strategy. However, i found [this wonderful plugin](http://pixelcone.com/fileuploader/) which uploads multiple files withour reloading the page and also shows a cool progress bar. The best thing about this plugin is that it doesn't uses flash and works on IE too. I strongly recommend using this plugin

Comment: seems you are successful in using struts2 in combination with Ajax for multiple upload . can you shed more light on this ?

Comment: first of all setup the usual code to upload a file using struts2. [This tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/12/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example.html) explains how to do that. Once you succeed in uplodaing in uploading and saving the usual way, just add this plugin's functionality by following the steps mentioned in [this page](http://pixelcone.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-script/). If you still face any problem, tell me about it

Answer (score 0):

Donot use taglibrary defined file upload for uploading. You can still use

common- fileupload to handle file upload. By doing this you can dynamically

add one more input type file element below the current input type upload using

javascript. I doubt if there is any way to do this using pure struts 1.3.5 :)  .